# Null Pointer Exception in a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, pointers, null, blackjack

In a blackjack program I'm writing I'm getting a null pointer exception in a while loop I'm using.

Here is the loop itself:

```
int total = 0; 
  for (int x = 5; x <= hitOrStayCounter; x++) 
  {

    total = total + temp[x].getBJ(); //Line 57 where the error is occuring. 
  }
```

Here is where and hitOrStayCounter and temp are defined:

```
int hitOrStayCounter=5;
Card[] temp = new Card[300];
```

Here is the getBJ method:

```
public int getBJ()
{
return bJValue; 
}
```

I suspect it is because I'm trying to use an array inside of my loop but inserting an int value into the brackets. I've tried to solve it and was wondering if you guys could help give me a solution. I couldn't find any similar questions, but if you find one please direct me to it and I'll delete this. Thanks for your time.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Blackjack.main(Blackjack.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at       edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

And then here is the loop where I initialized my temp values.

```
 while (hitOrStay.equalsIgnoreCase("hit"))
  {
    temp[hitOrStayCounter] = cardDeck.deal();
    System.out.println("You are delt a " + temp[hitOrStayCounter].getBJ()); 
    hitOrStayCounter = hitOrStayCounter + 2;
    System.out.println("Would you like to hit again?"); 
    hitOrStay = keyboard.next(); 
  }
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I'm currently writing my code in Dr. Java with the Java SE

Comment: which one is Line number 57?

Comment: @rookieB sorry let me comment that in.

Comment: "exception in a while loop I'm using" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hitOrStayCounter` is `5`. And you are starting your loop from `5`.

```js
for (int x = 0; x <= hitOrStayCounter; x++) 
{
    total = total + temp[x].getBJ(); 
}
```

If you are incriminating `hitOrStayCounter`, then it's ok.

Make sure your temp object is inialized.

```
Card[] temp = new Card[300]; This will not initialize
```

This will create 300 variables. Like

```
Card c1;
Card c2;..
```

You have to allocate each object as `temp[0]= new Card();` Do it in a loop. I am just giving example

Comment: Also the hitOrStayCounter shouldn't be equal to 5. I have a counter above where the hitOrStay Counter is incremented each time the user hits or is dealt a card.

Comment: have you intialized temp?

Comment: yes it's in the code above. It is a part of the Card class I wrote. Would it help to have that as well?

Comment: Didn't actually solve the problem I realized. My temp should already be intialized. I added more code in another edit to show where the temps are initialized in a loop above.